# Where are Kernel global variables stored?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules, variable, storage

I am currently writing a Linux kernel module. I am aware that in case of userspace programs, uninitialized global variables (exported to other modules using `EXPORT_SYMBOL`) are stored in BSS segment and initialized ones in Data Segment of userspace memory. But how are they stored in case of kernel code?

Are the function calls also included in Stack, in case of kernel code?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel has some notion of data segment, which sits in RAM (physical memory loaded by the kernel loader such as [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/), not [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)).

For details, examine the [linker scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.29/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts) used at kernel build time, perhaps something like `arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds` or other `*.lds` files.